# How to detect number of characters that can exactly fit on a pre defined length of text box?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I add a text box of length of 50px, And I want to count the exact number of characters (including whitespace) that perfectly fits inside that text box, I mean no character should be allowed to be typed inside the textbox that require the sliding of whole line toward left; I mean, in another other-words, we need to disallow the typist to further insert any letter as the line reaches up to the length of the text box.  Can we anyhow solve this by JavaScrip? Thanks for the help in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The whole logic is flawed as it would depend also on the size of the text inside the input. I'd put instead a limit of chars to be entered that don't go beyond. Using `maxlength` input attribute.

Anyways if you really wanna go this route, which I think is an overkill and not needed, then you can:

- Make use of `CanvasRenderingContext2D.measureText`, [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText)
- In order to do that you'd have to create a hidden [canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/kab/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) where to mimic your input text.
- After that you will need to check on input if the text goes beyond the input width and avoid any further keystrokes but still allow for deletion.

Find attached an example snippet, not optimised, of what I am talking about.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#form'),
      input = form.querySelector('input')

  const createAppendCanvas = form => {
    const canvas = document.createElement('Canvas')
    form.appendChild(canvas)
  }

  createAppendCanvas(form)

  const getTextMetrics = inputText => {
    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
          textWidth = Math.ceil(canvas.getContext('2d').measureText(inputText).width) + 10
    return textWidth
  }

  const disableTyping = (event, input) => {
    const inputText = event.target.value,
          inputWidth = input.clientWidth

    if (getTextMetrics(inputText) >= inputWidth) {
      event.preventDefault()
      return false
    }

  }

  input.addEventListener('keypress', event => disableTyping(event, input))
```

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
}

canvas {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: I  believe is an answer with a solution plus best practice, but to each his own mate 

Comment: @David784 Hi mate, have look now, what do you reckon? Still, I wouldn't encourage bad practice to people learning javascript, but I didn't quite process mentally the downvote ahah.

Comment: I really like your use of `canvas`...I've not used it much in the past and didn't know about `measureText`. It looks like a much better solution than mine!

Comment: And yes I can understand reluctance to go down a rabbit hole like this one. But I'm glad both you and @Cat posted your answers; I learned something new from both of you, and for me that's what it's all about. And I'm really glad you edited your answer; I felt guilty later for the downvote but couldn't change it. It wasn't a bad answer even though it was short...and truth be told I probably put way too many short answers as comments, when they should actually be answers.

Comment: Mel, Thanks for the answer. I did not use downvote on you, I haven't used stackoverflow in a while and hence I don't know if you can anyhow see who downvoted. But SOF knows that at least I didn't do so. I don't believe any logic is flawed if it is needed for whatever harmless purpose we want it to work for and if it is computable without creating any perceivable performance impact to a degree where your system of solution starts to feel sluggish. We create abstraction to solve problems, higher level languages are indeed abstractions to solve whatever we want. Here is your upvote though!

Comment: That's somewhat true, with today's computational power thanks god when it comes to working with very small amount of data we don't need to worry, THAT, much about perfecting to the most insane level of performance. Still I do highly support always native solutions but maybe you need it for some peculiar cases which in that case that'd do. Thanks to you and @David784 for making me learn a new thing today!

Answer (score 3):

As @mel-macaluso rightly points out, this is a very big rabbit hole to go down, and the standard practice is to use the [maxlength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/maxlength) attribute to limit the number of characters.

*Edit: You can also set the width of the `input` using [em](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems), which is proportional to the font size. (The name em was originally a reference to the width of the capital M in the typeface and size being used, which was often the same as the point size [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography))) A combination of width in `em` and `maxlength` will give a very rough approximation of what you may be trying to achieve.

However if you really want to be able to limit input based text length, this would serve as a **very** simplistic example of how you might get started.

#### Edit: I recommend @mel-macaluso's answer: he added an example using [CanvasRenderingContext2D.measureText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText), which I suspect is much more efficient than `getBoundingClientRect`.

First some disclaimers:

- This example doesn't take into account clipboard actions. That's a pretty big problem, and you'd be talking a lot more code to try to account for it (way beyond the scope of what can reasonably be done here).
- It's also rather resource intensive. The process doing a `getBoundingClientRect`, forces the browser to reflow the document contents an extra time. Depending on the size of the page this can be a big deal, and it's not something to be done lightly.

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('test');
// get font for input
var style = getComputedStyle(inp);
var maxWidth = inp.getBoundingClientRect().width;
var sizeTest = document.createElement('span');
// set font for span to match input
sizeTest.style.font = style.font;
inp.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) return;
  if(e.key && e.key.length===1) {
    sizeTest.textContent = inp.value;
    document.body.append(sizeTest);
    var w = sizeTest.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    sizeTest.remove();
    console.log(maxWidth, w, e.key, e.code);
    if(w>maxWidth) e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<input id='test'/>
```

So why is it so complex to do something like this? Fonts are tricky things. You have [variable width (proportional) fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportion), [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning), [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature), etc. It's very complex, and browsers don't provide access to most of this information.

So if you want to know how long a segment of text is, you generally have to put it in a span with the same font settings and then request the bounding dimensions.

Comment: I also discovered that we can measure width in `ch`, the width the character `0`, and that this tends to be roughly 60% of character height -- which explains why `offsetHeight/1.7` (or ~59%) was a reasonable predictor of character length in my minimal tests.

Answer (score 2):

Here's neat solution using nested spans (with a `contenteditable` inner span) as a proxy input.

```js
// Identifiers and dynamic styling
const innerSpan = document.querySelector("span.inner"),
      outerSpan = document.querySelector("span.outer");
  /* Threshold should be at least one character-width less than outerSpan.
     (This formula was pretty close for my few tests;
      for more precision and less flexibility, you can hard-code a value.) */
const estMaxCharWidth = innerSpan.offsetHeight / 1.7,
      thresholdWidth = outerSpan.offsetWidth - estMaxCharWidth;
innerSpan.style.minWidth = `${Math.floor(thresholdWidth)-3}px`; // defaults to 0 
innerSpan.style.minHeight = `${Math.floor(outerSpan.offsetHeight)-2}px`

// Listeners
innerSpan.addEventListener("focus", customOutline);
innerSpan.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyAndWidth);
innerSpan.addEventListener("blur", removeOutlineAndHandleText);


// Functions
function checkKeyAndWidth(e){
  // Runs when user presses a key, Conditionally prevents input
  if(e.code == "Enter" || e.keyCode == 13){
    e.preventDefault(); // Don't insert a new line
    e.target.blur(); // (In production, set the focus to another element)
  }
  else{
    // Some keys besides Enter are important, More could be added
    const whitelistCodes = ["Backspace", "Tab", "Escape", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "Insert", "Delete"];
    const whitelistKeyCodes = [8,9,27,37,39,45,46];
    // If the inner span is wide enough, stop accepting characters
    let acceptingCharacters = e.target.offsetWidth <= thresholdWidth;
    if(!acceptingCharacters && !whitelistCodes.includes(e.code) && !whitelistKeyCodes.includes(e.keyCode) && !whitelistKeyCodes.includes(e.which)){
      // Unauthorized incoming keystroke
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}

function customOutline(){
  // Runs when span gets focus, Needed for accessibility due to CSS settings
  outerSpan.style.borderColor = "DeepSkyBlue"; 
}

function removeOutlineAndHandleText(){
  // Runs when focus is lost
  outerSpan.style.borderColor = "Gray";
  if(innerSpan.length < 1){ innerSpan.innerHTML = " "; } // force content
  /* Since this is not a real input element, now might be the time to do something with the entered text */
}
```

```css
.outer{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px; /* Defaults to 0 */
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.inner{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none; /* Don't do this without calling customOutline on focus */
}
```

```html
<!-- requires that browser supports `contenteditable` -->
<span class="outer">
  <!-- space character in innerSpan may improve cross-browser rendering -->
 <span class="inner" contenteditable="true"> </span>
</span>
```

Comment: As mentioned in the HTML comments, this code requires that the browser supports `contenteditable (See https://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable) --  And workarounds for browser differences can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: Hi mate, not running on opera mini ahah, I spinned up a pen and still doesn't see to trigger, tried on firefox, safari, chrome all latest versions. I am curious to see the implementation working and learn from it, let me know if you manage to amend, cheers

Comment: @MelMacaluso, I noticed that if I single-click inside the span, the border turns blue, and even though no cursor appears at that point I can start typing and it works. But if I click inside a second time the border turns black again and I can't type until I click outside and then single-click inside again. Seems to be some odd focus/blur behaviour. Using latest chrome.

Comment: @David784 nice finding, probably the pitfall is relying on the focus event

Comment: @MelMacaluso, @David784 Thanks a lot for the feedback, folks. It helped me realize I had done a big dumb and edited the code after testing, without re-testing. The main thing was that I had removed `min-width` on the inner span. -- So I fixed that and did some "cross-browser-madness" troubleshooting to make all the core functionality work in Chrome/Firefox/Edge (although I still don't love how it looks in Firefox.) Can you let me know if it's working for you now?

Comment: @Cat my only worry, if any, is that you loose all the good stuff that comes from an input html element (attributes etc.)

Comment: @MelMacaluso No doubt. It's probably just for basic text, but unless the text is being copied to a real input for submission it can't be part of a form, so any validation would have to be done with regex, and autocomplete is right out.